# Find the first match after the particular element in rest of dom using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Hi i have to find the "findme" div in dom structure after a particular div
and find the first instance after the div using one Jquery.
following may be the dom structure:

```
ex1:
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="findme"></div>

ex2:
<div class="abc"></div>

 <div>
   <div class="findme"></div>
</div>

 ex3:
 <div>
   <div class="abc"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
   <div class="findme"></div>
</div>

 ex4:
 <div>
   <div class="abc"></div>
 </div>
  <div class="findme"></div>
```

above are some examples of dom structure in which i want to find "findme" first `div` after "abc" div using jquery
i tried using `after(),closest().nextAll().first()`
but i am not getting the query to match above all examples .
so please can anyone help me to find the div first element ("finme") after "abc" div

I want find the next "findme" div in complete dom after "abc" div and first occurrence of after "abc" div above are some examples the dom can be

Comment: This is unclear what you are expecting, i don't see any logic there. Why e.g in ex3, the parent of `findme` shouldn't be the matched one???

Comment: Corrected the missing check below and have tested it with all the cases you mentioned. Try it again and see if it fills you with happiness this time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could find to get this to work for all cases is to walk the entire DOM sequentially with a filter:

```
var foundAbc;
$('*').filter(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('abc')) {
    foundAbc = true;
  } else {
    if (foundAbc && $(this).hasClass('findme')) {
      foundAbc = false;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}).css('color','red');
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/LnLf79od/2/

You could wrap this behavior in a jQuery extension method if you wanted to make it reusable.

```
$.findNext = function(selector1, selector2) {
  var foundAbc;
  return $('*').filter(function() {
    if ($(this).is(selector1)) {
      foundAbc = true;
    } else {
      if (foundAbc && $(this).is(selector2)) {
        foundAbc = false;
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

and use like this:

```
$.findNext('.abc', '.findme').css('color', 'red');
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/LnLf79od/3/

Comment: if i remove all the abc tags then also its making red all the findme divs

Comment: if abc div exists then only find the next findme div first occurrence and make it red

Comment: @pareshm: That was not in your example, so missed it. It was a trivial bug (now fixed). Not worth a downvote but this site is full of anonymous "geniuses" bringing down the tone of the place :)

Comment: @pareshm: why are you asking me? I did not down vote you. I think it is a good question. I will up vote it now.

Comment: Another blind down-vote *on an accepted working answer*. Another coward. Typical :)